# Having session_id, can I bypass login form on remote server?

Tags: php, security, authentication, session

Third party zend encrypted system has Web API, that let's you login through it and acquire session_id (for later calls?). Then there's a task, how to bypass login form having that session_id.

Is something like this possible at all?

Comment: You can change the cookie your browser has registered to a specific site by typing this in your adddress bar `javascript:document.cookie='session_id=234y89575'`

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try this now.

Comment: Hmmm... it just echoes it back to me and does nothing..? Is there ant tut on this anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Yes , it is called [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).

Comment: Yeah,  but a session hijack require you to HAVE the session_id.

Comment: @The Rook: Have you read the title? *Having session_id...*

Answer (score 0):

Having session Identifier can bypass the login. HTTP is a stateless protocol and the server uses the session identifier to authenticate a keep track of a user's device when they are already logged in. Therefore, by stealing another user's session identifier, you can trick the server into thinking that you are that user by sending that user's session identifier to the server.

A complete writeup on session hijacking and all of the session hijacking attacks can be found [Here](http://blog.joshuakissoon.com/tutorials/session-hijacking-0).